# Можете мне прояснить что здесь по чём?

Tags: css

Здравствуйте можете пояснить что здесь написано и почему написано именно так ?

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    font-size: 100.01%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    font: 16px/1.41 "proxima-nova",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    color: #000;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
}
.wrapper:after {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: А что смущает? Какая строка?

Comment: font-size: 100.01%
зачем в body добавлено в height important
ну а wrapper мне вообще не понятен и ещё зачем ему добавлен after ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Без HTML, конечно, разобраться сложнее. Судя по CSS, это довольно древний файл. Конструкция

```
html {
    font-size: 100.01%;
 {
```

ставилась раньше, чтобы избежать следующих проблем с отображением:

- исключает проблему в IE/Win с непропорциональным увеличением или
  уменьшением размера шрифта, если он установлен в em;
- в Opera шрифт 100% мог отобразиться более мелким, чем в других браузерах;
- 101% нельзя было использовать из-за проблем с размерами в Safari.

Этот хак в том числе использовался в одном из первых reset.css.
Но это было давно (примерно до 2010 года), потом основные ошибки в браузерах исправили. В последних версиях [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) этого уже нет за ненадобностью.

Строку

```
height: 100% !important;
```

из `body` можно сократить, убрав `!important`, он тут ни к чему. 100% высота `html` и `body` ставится для того, чтобы страница занимала всю высоту экрана.

По поводу `wrapper` - код также можно сократить, убрать ненужные `!important`, а зачем там `after` - надо смотреть на сайте, вероятно, туда что-то вставлено после самого `wrapper`.